# Python 101 - Variable Name Substitution

Tags: python, loops, substitution

A pretty basic question...was wondering if there is a way to easily substitute part of a variable name with the looping index?

i.e.

```
value_1 = 1
value_2 = 2
value_3 = 3

for i in range (1,4):
    print value_i
```

Obviously the above code wouldn't work...but is it possible to substitute the number part of variable name with index i in Python?

Thank you.

Comment: You can definitely add those values to list and iterate the list.

Comment: Beside the point, but wouldn't recommend learning Python 2 at this point since it hit end-of-life in January. Python 3 is much better anyway. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], plus [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) tl;dr use a list instead

Comment: It's worth taking the time to explore python's lists and dictionaries. Once you internalize those a bit, you won't want to do this. It is *really* the wrong way forward.

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone's input. I did end up using a list. But it's nice to know the globals() function as well.

Answer (score 1):

Other than using a list, which is the obvious solution, you can also access variables using `globals()`:

```
value_1 = 1
value_2 = 2
value_3 = 3

for i in range(1, 4):
    var_name = f"value_{i}"
    print(globals()[var_name])
```

The result would be:

```
1 
2 
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value_1 = 1
value_2 = 2
value_3 = 3

for i in range (1,4):
    print(globals()['value_%s' % i])
```

I would advise use of dictionaries or lists instead